# Retrive counts of two columns from two diffrent tables with third table using join query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables: `COUNTRY`, `STATE`, `CITY`

This is my `Country` table with two columns:

```
CountryID, Name
```

This is my `State` table:

[image: state table]

This is my `City` table:

[image: city table]

I want to retrieve the count of states and cities according to the `country` table using join query.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Text (formatted) instead of images. Also show us the expected result, and your current query attempt.

Comment: in country table i have two columns, "CountryID","Name". and country code is primary key, In state table i have "StateID", "CountryID", "StateName" and i have stateID as primary key and CountryID as foriegn key,   In City Table i have "CityID","StateID","CityName", here CityID as Primary key and StateID is Forign Key, as a result i want  Three Coulnms "CountryId", "No of States" , "No of city".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipping the fact that your question is not asked well - try this query, it should work for you:

```
WITH
tab_a AS (
SELECT c.countryid, COUNT (s.stateid) AS state_num
FROM country c
LEFT JOIN state s ON c.countryid = s.countryid
GROUP BY c.countryid
),
tab_b AS (
SELECT c.countryid, COUNT (cc.cityid) city_num
FROM country c
LEFT JOIN state s ON c.countryid = s.countryid
LEFT JOIN city cc ON s.stateid = cc.stateid
GROUP BY c.countryid
)
SELECT a.countryid,
       a.state_num,
       b.city_num
FROM tab_a a JOIN tab_b b ON a.countryid=b.countryid
```